# Getting new Id with Entity Framework Core after ORACLE INSERT

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

my entity models were generated by entityframework core scaffolding

I read a few posts and have not gotten the new Id after a successful Oracle insert with Entity Framework Core. Here is my code so far that I copied from the post

```
var result = await this.myDbContent.MyEntity.AddAsync(myEntity);
var result1 = await this.myDbContent.SaveChangesAsync();
await transaction.CommitAsync();

var myId = this.myDbContent.Entry(myEntity).GetDatabaseValues(); // get null return

return myEntity.myId; // is 0
```

I checked the db and I see the new record but I can't retrieve the new ID.

Before the Add, it was 0 and was never updated with the new id value.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: your `myId` is not database-generated. If it's not configured by convention, you need to configure it explicitly by either using `DatabaseGeneratedAttribute` or fluent api.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here and it explains how to use DatabaseGeneratedAttribute with EntityFrameWork

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/databasegenerated-attribute